# Only one row in UIdatePicker

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I would liketo have the use of a UIDatePicker that is just one row displayed instead of three. Three rows take up way too much real-estate!

HELP!!!

I am able to rotate and resize the control without any great stress, but have yet to figure out how to only display the one row.
Thank you,

Comment: Do you mean one column? What exactly do you want it to display? - hour, minute, second?

Comment: I want to display names in array.. in single column

Answer (score -1):

Use UIPickerView with UIDatePickerDelegate and UIDatePickerDataSource, not UIDatePicker.

Here's a [manual](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/UIPickerView/UIPickerViewExample.html).